# How to click on html element and have href change on each page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, python-3.x

Can I write a script in python3 so I can click on this?

```
<a data-href="/twistyourself/rate/2074/fde3342f6097f6f62ead217d788344d3" 
    data-callback="tyRated" 
    title="Vote" 
    class="love section-gallery__vote">
        vote
</a>
```

If yes, how to resolve it so that `fde3342f6097f6f62ead217d788344d3` changes every time you refresh the page to a new string of characters and letters?

Comment: Your post is a bit confusing. Please read this SO article. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can select the element with this:

```
$("parent_element_or_body").find("[data-callback=tyRated")
```